# Updating State of Parent component from Child Component (Tab Navigator)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React and React Native and I am trying to build an cooking recipe app. I am trying to update my dish state in DishTabNavigator.js from DishIngredients.js so that I can send the data to firebase from DishTabNavigator.js, however I do not know how I can update the state. I tried lifting the state up but I couldn't do it. Been stuck on this for a day now. Any help would be appreciated

DishTabNavigator.js

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export default function MyTabs({ navigation }) {
  const [dish, setDish] = useState([{ ingredients: [] }]);
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.iconright}>
          <Text>Send dish to Firebase</Text>
          <FontAwesome name="save" size={24} color="black" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    });
  });
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Ingredient"
        component={DishIngredients}
        ingredients={dish}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

DishIngredients.js

```
class DishIngredients extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ingredients: [],
      textInput: [],
    };
//Add TextInput
  addTextInput = (index) => {
    let textInput = this.state.textInput;
    textInput.push(
      <TextInput
        style={styles.textInput}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.addValues(text, index)}
      />
    );
    this.setState({ textInput });
  };

//Function to add values into the states
  addValues = (text, index) => {
    let dataArray = this.state.ingredients;
    let checkBool = false;
    if (dataArray.length !== 0) {
      dataArray.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.index === index) {
          element.text = text;
          checkBool = true;
        }
      });
    }
    if (checkBool) {
      this.setState({
        ingredients: dataArray,
      });
    } else {
      dataArray.push({ text: text, index: index });
      this.setState({
        ingredients: dataArray,
      });
    }
  };

  //function to console the output
  getValues = () => {
    console.log("Data", this.state.ingredients);
    this.props.ingredients = this.state.ingredients;
    console.log(this.props.ingredients);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.icon}>
          <View style={{ margin: 10 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Ionicons
                name="add"
                size={24}
                color="black"
                onPress={() => this.addTextInput(this.state.textInput.length)}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={{ margin: 10 }}>
            <Button title="Remove" onPress={() => this.removeTextInput()} />
          </View>
        </View>
        {this.state.textInput.map((value) => {
          return value;
        })}
        <Button title="Get Values" onPress={() => this.getValues()} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default DishIngredients;
```

Comment: You can do it if you render the child component directly or, in this case, with redux.

Comment: @Shira where exactly in `DishIngredients` you wanna `setDish` ?

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli at the Button, "Get Values", once I know how I can pass states between the two files, I can move it around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing a lot in your current code you can do like this

```
const addIngredient = (ingredient) => {
    // TODO: ingredient
  };

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Ingredient">
        {(props) => (
          <DishIngredients
            {...props}
            ingredients={dish}
            addIngredient={addIngredient}
          />
        )}
      </Tab.Screen>
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
```

As you see there is a function `addIngredient` (You can rename as you wish) that will be introduced as `prop` in `DishIngredients` like `this.props.addIngredient(<Your Ingredient text>)`.

**ReactContext** also a nice solution above but I think, this will force your app re-render every time your context changes. It might impact on your performance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **React Context**

```
const DishContext = React.createContext({
  dish: [],
  setDish: () => {},
});

export const useDishContext = () => React.useContext(DishContext);

export const AppDishProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [dish, setDish] = useState([{ingredients: []}]);

  const defaultDish = {
    dish,
    setDish,
  };

  return (
    <DishContext.Provider value={defaultDish}>{children}</DishContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Then

```
/** Wrap your TabNavigator with AppDishProvider */
<AppDishProvider>
  <YourTabNavigator />
</AppDishProvider>
```

Then

```
/**
 * In DishIngredients, or your TabNavigator...
 * You get access to dish-state, and setDish using your
 * custom-hook `useDishContext`
 */

 const { dish, setDish } = useDishContext();
```

And if you're using class-based component

```
class DishIngredient extends React.Component {
  static contextType = DishContext;

  /**
   * Current context-value could be accessed by
   * `this.context`
   */

  render() {
    const {dish, setDish} = this.context;
    /** .... */
  }
}
```

*Assuming you're not having redux wired in your app... ReactContext is your way to go...*

Comment: I'm pretty sure your method will work, I was also thinking of switching to react context as well. This might be another question but how would I call the useDishContext() since my DishIngredient is a class rather than a function. Most of the solutions I looked up were more of react specific rather than react native

Comment: It shouldve work, however when I console.log the dish, it is undefined, when I try using setDish it gives an error that it is not a function (probably because it is also undefined), the only way I can get the messages is if I use the Hook inside a function without the curly braces, then I can get the values but not be able to use the setDish